# How to create a view similar to iPod player?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm creating an app that shows a list of items one by one on the screen. Each item will have a name and phone number, and will be displayed in a view called `person view`. My project is similar to the iPod music player view:

[image]

However, instead of showing the album image, I want to show my `person view`. Could someone explain me how to achieve the navigation when the user hits `|<<` or `>>|`? Also, how can I build a similar view? Any code snippet/blueprint would be quite helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: @sudo rm -rf : Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is that Apple's app store review guidelines contain advice that apps that reproduce iPod controls may be rejected. My guess is that this is probably meant more to discourage apps from using a control like the traditional iPod jog wheel, but it's something you may want to be careful about.

Comment: Thanks for the info , by the way my application navigation system is going to be similar but not the UI. I put this question because am confused with showing the same view with different data along with the transition.